# E212 Can't open file for writing

Tags: vim

I was trying to add syntax highlighting to my vim which is located inside of `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`.

but even as `sudo` when I attempt to save I get the error: `E212 Can't open file for writing`.

Inside of `vimrc` I see it says `"vimrc" [readonly] 14L, 5578`.

How do I change that to allow for read and write?

So I ran a `vim vimrc` which put me in the config file, tapped down to the last line and hit the O button on the keyboard and wrote `syntax on`. When I went to `:wq!` thats when I got the error. Same thing when I run `sudo vim vimrc` or `sudo su -` then `vim vimrc`.

Comment: since it's a file used by vim maybe edit it with something other than vim

Comment: @RobertLongson, I tried with my code editor and got `EPERM: operation not permitted` and this was after adding my password for sudo privileges.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing files in `/usr/share`. Those will be overwritten on package update. Why can't you make your own `vimrc` file in your home directory and add this there?

Comment: @RobertLongson, so for the `vimrc` I have `-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel`. can you suggest something better than `chmod 777`?

Comment: I will ask the silly question. When trying to edit this Vim file you did close Vim first?

Comment: @David, I do not understand that question. How do you close a file and then edit it? I will clarify what I did in the post, perhaps that can help.

Comment: What file? I clearly meant the application.

Comment: @David, please read above for the steps I took, hopefully that will clarify.